# Rendering Problems every time I add a theme

Tags: android

I'm working on a new activity which I wanted to be blank by default. I then go into change the theme at `activity_main.xml` I changed it to "Black.NoTitleBar" which is the one I'm trying to work with. I get a rendering problem I look up the details seems like an easy fix just update. So I open up Android's SDK update tool. I download the recommended packages. Try the afforestation process again with the same result.

## Notes:

- I'm using 6.0 **API 23**
  Packages listed as installed in my SDK manager: *SDK Platform*, *ARM EABI v7a System Image*, and *Google API*
- I haven't touched any java files everything is default and lists no error.
  Here are the exception details:
- I saw a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345797/rendering-problems-while-changing-the-theme) with the same issue however their solution didn't work for me.

## Exception Details

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AppCompat themes, since you are using Android's Support Libraries. This is evident by the very first line of the exception.

If you do not need an action bar, you can use AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar as your theme.

Comment: Thanks again, this was driving me crazy